# update xml file with batch

Tags: xml, windows, file, batch-file, insert-update

1. I have been searching for an hour with no luck
2. My boss wants it to be a batch file

I have a xml file that contains the following.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <profiledoc default="*** Last Run ***">
    <profile name="*** Last Run ***" >
    <workingdir>c:\proj</workingdir>
    <somestuff>none</somestuff>
    <smpnumprocs>4</smpnumprocs>
    <otherstuff></otherstuff>
    <llama>FLUFFY</llama>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <customexe></customexe>
    <addlparams></addlparams>
    <graphicsdevice>win32</graphicsdevice>
    </profile>
    </profiledoc>
```

We want to set `<smpnumprocs>4</smpnumprocs>` (which is the number of processors used) to 2
therefore, the line should look like this `<smpnumprocs>2</smpnumprocs>`

I figured out how to get to the value I want with this

```
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=><  " %%a IN ('TYPE %LOCAL_FILE% ^| FIND "<smpnumprocs>"') DO SET NUM_PROCS=%%a
```

Now how do I change the value?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: @kjp No sir I already tried that and it does not fix my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use script I wrote:

```
@echo OFF
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if "%~1" == "" (
    echo Please provide xml file path as a first parameter.
    exit /B 1
)

if not exist "%~1" (
    echo Xml file with given path does not exist.
    exit /B 2
)

if exist "%~1.tmp" del /F /Q "%~1.tmp"

for /F "delims=" %%G in (%~1) do (
    set LINE=%%G
    if not "!LINE!" == "!LINE:smpnumprocs=!" (
        set LINE=!LINE:4=2!
    )
    >> "%~1.tmp" echo !LINE!
)

del /F /Q "%~1"
ren "%~1.tmp" "%~1"

@endlocal
```

Script scans through given xml file and finds line with `smpnumprocs` in it. If that kind of line is found, it substitutes 4 to 2.

All lines are dumped to `<xmlFilePathHere>.tmp` file, which replaces original file at the end.

Comment: This will produce problems with empty lines, lines with the text `ON`, `OFF` or  `/?` and removes characters from lines like `Hello ! A caret^`

Comment: This is a solution crafted for a given xml file. There are no such characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called xmlstarlet, which can do that easily:

```
xml ed -u "/xml/snumprocs" -v 2 /path/to/your.xml
```