# Store Multiline String in Batch Variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to remove a string that may occur inside a file. The string has many lines. **Can I perform this action using a Batch script?**

I've heard that you cant have variables with more than one line in Batch? The string will come from another file that I will read into a variable using Batch.

The following code seems to only store the 1st/last line of a file in the string?? Whats going wrong?

```
Rem Read file and store all contents in string
Set replace=
Set target=
Set OUTFILE=res.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (myFile.txt) do set target=%target% %%i

echo %target%
Rem When I print target I only have one line not many lines?? Whats going wrong

Rem Remove the target string from myOtherFile.txt: this code is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type myOtherFile.txt"') do (
SET string=%%A
SET modified=!string:%target%=%replace%!

echo !modified! >> %OUTFILE%
)
```

Comment: You can use the helper batch file `findrepl.bat` with the /v switch and remove a block of text from a file by specifying the start and end terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (myFile.txt) do set "target=!target! %%i"
echo %target%
```

Inside a code block you need always `delayed expansion` for variables with variable values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change last to:

```
echo !target!
```