# windows bat script find replace every file in folder and subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, find

First of all let me just say that I'm completely new to scripting.

I'm trying to develop a script which will find a given string and replace it with another given string. It must do this for every file in the folder/subfolders.

This must be a bat file. Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
set RESULT_FILE="result.txt"
set /p "var1=Enter the String to Find: "
set /p "var2=Enter the String to Replace with: "

pushd %~p0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S *.js') do (
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%c in ('find /i /c "%var1%" "%%a"') do (
    if %%c neq 0 (
        echo %var1%
    )
 )
) 

popd
```

This is returning the found variable, I'm just struggling on how I can replace it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: Do you want to rename the file, or do you want to replace strings inside the files?

Comment: Can it be just native scripting (PowerShell, VBScript, JScript) or does it have to be exclusively cmd.exe?

Comment: I forget where I found it but somewhere here. I want to replace the strings inside the files yes. I'm using an alternative I found here http://findandreplace.sourceforge.net/ which works pretty great. Does just what I need. Thanks for the help guys, I'd still be interested in seeing a solution out of curiosity.

Comment: I posted the link already in my answer: [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately sed doesn't work. It says that it is an unrecognized command.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) for Windows?

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A-D *.js') do sed -ibak "s/%var1%/%var2%/g" "%%~fa"
```

```
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed
  -f script-file, --file=script-file
                 add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
  -i[suffix], --in-place[=suffix]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
  -l N, --line-length=N
                 specify the desired line-wrap length for the `l' command
  -r, --regexp-extended
                 use extended regular expressions in the script.
  -s, --separate
                 consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous
                 long stream.
  --text     switch to text mode
  -u, --unbuffered
                 load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush
                 the output buffers more often
      --help     display this help and exit
  -V, --version  output version information and exit

If no -e, --expression, -f, or --file option is given, then the first
non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret.  All
remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are
specified, then the standard input is read.
```

Answer (score 1):

The link below might be of some help. The proposed solution is to create a new file with the replaced strings, and to delete the old file.

[How to replace substrings in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

With [fart](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/), you can do what you want in a single line of windows bat script.

```
fart.exe -r "C:\path\to\folder\*.*" string_to_be_replaced replace_string
```

where `-r` stands for `Process sub-folders recursively`.