# Replace a string with empty string inside a file using Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to replace a string in a file A, with empty string. And I need to do it using Batch script.

Input: A.txt
A.txt contains "xyz", which I need to replace with empty string in same file A.txt.

I need to replace only "xyz" from the file A.txt, not the entire file. The file A.txt contains contains several other strings.

Please let me know if possible.

Comment: http://winitpro.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/batchscript/ you should take a look

Comment: Have a look at this - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: My favorite solution is [REPL.BAT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the `xyz` with nothing, which is effectively an empty string.

```
echo.>a.txt
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to replace only "xyz" with an empty string, not the entire file content. But the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @dbenham The OP hasn't replied so anything could be the case. :)  I took the question at face value and he didn't mention anything else in the file.