# Replacing symbols or line break in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found a batch script that changes a string to another string.

Below batch script changes every 'bath' to 'hello' in test.txt

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=test.txt    set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=bath
set REPLACETEXT=hello

set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
SET string=%%A
SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

(copied from [How to replace substrings in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file))

But what I want to do is changing every '△▽' to 'newline and xy' in test.txt
For example, if test.txt is

```
abc△▽def
```

then the result should be

```
abc
xydef
```

Before attacking this problem, I tried easier-looking problem : changing every '△▽' to 'xy'. But this easier-looking problem looks even difficult to me. I just simply changed bath to △▽, and hello to xy in the above script. Then the script didn't work. The reason I guess is - since △,▽ are symbols.

Could you teach me how to express symbol or line break, tab in the refered batch script ?

Comment: Sorry, but what kind of a text file does include `WHITE UP-POINTS TRIANGLE` and `WHITE DOWN-POINTS TRIANGLE`? What is the encoding of that text file? Which text editor is used to open that text file and can properly show that triangles?

Comment: Just windows notepad. The encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: My final purpose is making windows batch script custom string replacer. I use windows notepad. The encoding is UTF-8, but I don't care that much because I can change the encoding at the final step... ANSI or UNICODE are accepted too. Thank you

Comment: There is a solution to replace triangles with "xy". First change the codepage: `CHCP 1254` Then convert file to ANSI `TYPE INTEXTFILE.txt > ASCII.txt` The `ASCII.txt` file includes weird characters (`¢-`, ALT+0162 and ALT+45) instead of triangles. It is easy to replace them with "xy" characters. But I wasn't able to find a solution for adding newlines and I don't know if the solution I mentioned can be integrated with a solution to addnewlines. The final file will be encoded in ANSI.

Comment: Sorry. You should use -I think- `CHCP 1252` instead of `CHCP 1254`.

Comment: it may be much easier in powershell because UTF-8 support in cmd.exe and other Windows tools is very bad

Answer (score 0):

The **WHITE UP-POINTS TRIANGLE** is encoded in UTF-8 with 3 bytes with the hexadecimal code values `E2 96 B3` and the **WHITE DOWN-POINTS TRIANGLE** with `E2 96 BD`.

[How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/) contains several answers with suggestions on how to replace strings in batch mode using console applications or even just Windows standard commands.

My favorite tool for such replaces is **Xchang32.exe** from **Clay's Utilities for Win32**.

**Important note:** Clay Ruth, author of **Xchang32.exe** and owner of domain `clayruth.com` died years ago. For that reason the ZIP file with this tool is not available anymore in world wide web although it was permitted explicitly to distribute this package free of charge according to read me file in the ZIP file.

This console application replaces bytes by bytes and can be used therefore for any file type, for binary files as well as text files of any encoding.

This tool with the following parameters makes the replace as you want.

```
xchang32.exe Test.txt "^xE2^x96^xB3^xE2^x96^xBD" "^x0D^x0Axy"
```

All `△▽` are replaced by a carriage return (0D) and a line-feed (0A) and the characters `xy` in file `Test.txt`. In case of file `Test.txt` is a UNIX file with using just a line-feed as line terminator, remove `^x0D` from replace string.

Of course the same replacement could be also done with a UTF-8 aware text editor like UltraEdit which even has a **Replace in Files** command capable to replace UTF-8 encoded strings in all files of a folder or folder tree.