# How to disable both `eol` and `delims` options of `for /F`?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

The `for` command with the `/F` switch is used to parse lines of text strings (literal strings, read from text files, or retrieved from command line output) and to parse each to one or more tokens.

How can I get a line of text as it is, without any characters replaced nor any lines ignored?

I know that `for /F "delims=" %L in (*) do echo."%L"` returns each parsed (non-empty) line unedited. However, since the `eol` option defaults to `;`, every line starting with that character will be ignored.
If I use `for /F "tokens=* eol=" %L in (*) do echo."%L"`, <s>I disable the `eol` option</s> *[**Edit:** This claim is not true, `"eol="` does not disable the `eol` option, but it defines `"` as the `eol` character!]*, but the `delims` option defaults to space and tab, so any leading spaces and/or tabs become removed.
(Use `%%L` within batch files. The `*` stands for any valid source of text string here.)

So my question in other words: is there a way to specify *no* `delims` **and** *no* `eol` characters?

I tried to specify two option strings (`"eol=" "delims="`) but such results in a syntax error. So does option string `"eol=delims="`.

**Note:** This problem does not persist when tokenizing, that is, when the `delims` option is set, because that seems to be applied with a higher priority than `eol` (strangely but luckily), so you can "hide" `eol` behind `delims` by specifying a `delims` character also as `eol`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) you will be never able to force bat to not [ignore empty / delimiter-only](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=7265#p7265) lines.This can be (sort-of) worked around by piping to `findstr /R /N "^"` command and use options like `"tokens=1* delims=:"` and get only the second token

2) To deactivate [eol and delim](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1544) at the same time you can use this syntax:

```
For /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in (file.txt) do echo.%%a
```

though the empty lines still will be ignored.

Comment: 1) yes, I'm aware of the fact that empty lines are skipped; the work-around usinf `findstr` is a good idea although it fails when a line starts with `:`; 2) thanks a lot for this syntax, I've never seen this before; does this define the space to be the delimiter?? translated into the standard quoted version it would read `"tokens=* delims= eol="` when I got it correct, right?

Comment: ad 2) I just found out that `"[...] eol="` defines the `"` as end-of-line char. (how stupid is that??); thus, thanks again for the hint to the non-quoted version!! I also found out that `delims` must be the last option only in case you want define a space as the delimiter; so in this case, when you want that together with no `eol`, the only chance is to provide `eol^=^<new-line><new-line>^<space>delims^=^<space>`; is that correct, or is there a simpler (more legible) variant?

Comment: The `tokens^=*^ ` does no harm, but neither does it serve any purpose. All you need is `for /f delims^= eol^= %%a in ...`

Comment: @aschipfl 1) With `findstr /n` you can build a [bullet proof loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5274061/463115), as each line begins with a number you don't get any problems 2) You don't need the linefeed version, the `delims^=^ ...` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, @jeb! 1) I meant `findstr /N` to fail with `delims=:` for leading `:`s, but I didn't think of `var:*:=:` expansion; 2) the line-feed version is needed for _no_ `eol` but `delims=<space>`, right?

Comment: @jeb, 2) finally I found a solution for specifying _no_ `eol` but a `delims=<space>` avoiding the <line-feed> version: `"eol=  delims= "` (it seems the `eol` can be "hidden" behind `delims` if the latter is given, so `delims` has got a higher priority than `eol`);

Comment: @dbenham, do you know if there is any difference in performance between `"tokens=* delims="` and `"delims="`?

Comment: how to use variable tokens in the `for .. eol^= ..` ? for example: `set "v=2"
</br> for %%g in (1 2 3) do (
</br> set "v=%%g"
</br> for /f tokens^=!v!*^ delims^=^  %%h in ("11 22 33 44") do echo %%h
</br> )` . `![_]!`, `%%[_]` , `%~[number]` and `%[number]`, with or without the ^ , doesn't work .