# How to read all content from text flie in single variable in Batch Script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

This is my first experience in batch script, i am trying to read text file content and trying to set its content in single variable i am using .bat file to run script but script not working.
i want to set all content of file in single variable.
tried most of example but failure.
below is my script which i am trying

```
cd "C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop"
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Test.txt) do set Build=%%x
pause >nul
exit
```

This is my Text File

[image]

And
below result is showing

[image]

**i want it in single variable**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd "C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "useback delims=" %%x in ("Test.txt") do set "Build=!build! %%x"
echo %build%
pause >nul
exit
```

Mind that the max length of a string you can assign to a variable is 8191 symbols.
Also some special symbols could break the script above (`%`,`!` ..)

Comment: yes its working thank you so much, can i concatenate with ',' comma in specific place

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu - yes you can. Use `set "Build=!build! , %%x"`

Answer (score 0):

> i want to set all content of file in single variable.

In batch, the only way is to construct a multi-line variable yourself, named `!LF!`

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::Change this
set "file=%~f0"
if NOT EXIST "%file%" exit /b 1

::Initialize & empty variables
( set LF=^
%= 0x0D Form Feed =%
)
set "lines="
set "data="

::Count lines
FOR /F tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in (
'2^>nul findstr /N "^" "%file%"'
) do set /a "lines+=1"

::Read file using SET /P
<"%file%" (
  for /L %%a in (1 1 %lines%) do (
    set "x=" %= Workaround for empty lines =%
    set /p "x="
    set "data=!data!!LF!!x!"
  )
)

::Print data
echo(!data!

ENDLOCAL
pause & exit /b
```

The `FOR /F tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^=` disables `eol` by [escaping every delimiter](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1544). **Warning**: `"eol="` **DOES NOT** disable `eol`, but [sets the quote `"` as the end-of-line character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192678/how-to-disable-both-eol-and-delims-options-of-for-f)!

---

Disadvantages:

- **SLOW**: On my machine, it takes 2 seconds for a 2000 lines file, printing the variable excluded
- The line ending style (`\n` or `\r\n` is ignored, and always set to `\n`)
- Additional `\n` at the beginning of variable

Advantages:

- **SAFE**: Always works for any file with printable ASCII characters (0x20 ~ 0x7E)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @dbenham's `CERTUTIL` [method](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=57866#p57866). It is foolproof against `<CR> <LF> ! ^`...
See [more tricks with certutil](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=57918#p57918) for the ["poorly documented"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) switches explained in depth.

```
@echo off
====SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


set "B=^!"
set "C=^"
set ^"L=^
%===Line Feed===%
"
for /F %%C in ('wmic qfe list') do set "R=%%C" Carriage Return


>nul 2>&1 certutil -f -encodehex Test.txt "%temp%\hex.txt" 4


pushd "%temp%"
>expand.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (hex.txt) do for %%B in (%%A) do (
    set "char=%%B"
    REM ! --> !B!
    set "char=!char:21=21 42 21!"
    REM ^ --> !C!
    set "char=!char:5e=21 43 21!"
    REM <CR> --> !R!
    set "char=!char:0a=21 4c 21!"
    REM <LF> --> !L!
    set "char=!char:0d=21 52 21!"
    echo(!char!
  )
)

>nul 2>&1 certutil -f -decodehex expand.txt rawContent.txt
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (rawContent.txt) do set "fileContent=%%A"


del hex.txt expand.txt rawContent.txt
popd


echo(!fileContent!
```