# What does a ¶ (paragraph marker) in a Windows batch file mean?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5274880/1270789) with the line:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do
```

However, there is no explanation as to what the "¶" is doing there. StackOverflow search strips out the character, and Google offers me pictures of ladies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a character that shouldn't occur in the target file, so essentially it's the same as `delims="` (ie. no delimiters.)

Tha having been said, the fact that the code includes `tokens=1*` means that the first token (that part of the line up to, but not including [*any member of the set of delimiter characters*] will be assigned to `%%A` and the remainder of the line to `%%B`, so it would appear that the author is expecting that character in the file.