# How to remove strings from a text file using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that can remove a certain string from a text file. Eg. Here's what is looks like in text_file.txt:

```
test_time 1.4567s

test_time 2.1456s

test_time 1.45267s
```

I would like to remove "test_time" and the new_text_file.txt would look like this:

```
1.4567s
2.1456s
1.45267s
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a batch file to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=2" %A in (text_file.txt) do Echo %A >> New__file.txt
```

See `for /?` for help. Use %%A in a batch file, %A if typing.