# .bat file to merge .txt into one file, including filename but separated by a ';'

Tags: sql, batch-file, logging, concatenation

I'm having trouble with a kinda specific problem.

The monitoring software (used for robots in the manufacturing halls) used by the company i am working for, generates a log file (.sdat) every 15 minutes. The content of a log file looks like this:

The syntax: `Time;machine;status`

`13:53:23;KP85;ms:9999`

`13:53:49;KP85;ms:3`

`13:54:54;KP85;ms:4`

`14:06:04;KP85;ms:9999`

`13:51:38;Robot1;ms:9999`

etc...

I've managed to concatenate all the log files into one big file, including the filename at the start of each new row, like this:

The syntax: `Filename:Time;Machine;Status`

`01-03-2016-00-20.sdat:0:07:40;KP65;ms:3`

`01-03-2016-00-20.sdat:0:09:09;KP65;ms:4`

`01-03-2016-00-20.sdat:0:09:11;KP65;ms:3`

`01-03-2016-00-20.sdat:0:09:13;KP65;ms:4`

etc..

The reason I did this is because i need the time as well as the date(which is included in the filename) a certain status for a machine has been logged. However, if i import this into SQL management studio, it recognizes 3 columns instead of 4, because the filename and first column(time) are separated by a ':' instead of a ';'. I tried solving it with an SQL Query, separating the date and time with a LEFT() and RIGHT(), but guess what: the time field format changes when the time switches from 9:59:59 to 10:00:00, creating an extra character for the time field (so the data in the column would look like this ':9:59:59', which isn't a valid time field). Perhaps it could be done with SQL but it just seems to me like it would take too much complexity in the SQL code for such a small problem.

So at this point, i thought it would be better to tackle this problem early on; within the batch file which generates the large file, so Management Studio does recognize 4 instead of 3 columns. This is how my .bat file looks like at the moment:

`@echo off 
findstr "^" *.sdat >output.txt`

What do i have to do to get this right?

Thanks in advance,

Mike Sohns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
(for %%f in (*.sdat) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (%%f) do @echo %%f;%%a
))>output.txt
```

NOTE: this will swallow empty lines, but I think in your case that's not a problem. If yes, the code can be adapted.

Comment: empty lines don't matter, but it cannot generate output because it can't find %%i

Comment: Alright, thanks. will try it on monday when i'm back at work!

Comment: Thanks Stephan, your code works! It now generates lines like this:

01-03-2016-00-20.sdat;0:09:13;KP65;ms:4

which is exactly what i was looking for. However, it does take a lot more time to generate the file, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given that all the log files you are concatenating have the sdat extension, you have to replace sdat: for sdat; in order to have a ; separated CSV.

To achieve this, you can use the batch script in this other answer([How to replace substrings in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file)), that replaces substrings in a text file using a batch script.

Comment: is it possible to search and replace in text that is being generated(the filename at the start of each row) by the same batch file?