# conda list different between Windows' terminal and PyCharm's terminal

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I created an environment through PyCharm when I created a new project.
I then installed some packages (including scikit-learn).

When I look at `conda list` in PyCharm's terminal I see the following
[image]

but when I look at `conda list` in Windows' terminal I see this:
[image]

So, no new packages listed here... Why?

To add on my hate for Windows, in my PyCharm project I still see this:
[image]

Why in the world??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out.

PyCharm on Windows does not actually activate environments: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924787/pycharm-terminal-doesnt-activate-conda-environment#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924787/pycharm-terminal-doesnt-activate-conda-environment#_=_) , just great...

After installing Git and experimenting with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66523735/3751931), I
went to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal and replaced the value in "Shell path" with "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"

It seems to work.