# Properly activating conda environments in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda, qgis

I have PyCharm (PyCharm 2023.2.4 (Community Edition)) and Anaconda (miniforge3) installed. Anaconda is *not* configured to automatically an environment such as `base`.

PyCharm advertises support for conda environments: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

I have an environment "`myenv`" where the `qgis` package is installed via conda-forge. QGIS comes with some additional Python modules and the conda package includes a set of activation scripts in `.../envs/myenv/etc/conda/activate.d/` to add those to the `PYTHONPATH`.

If I run `conda activate myenv` my PYTHONPATH results in

```
/home/user/miniforge3/envs/myenv/share/qgis/python/plugins:/home/user/miniforge3/envs/myenv/share/qgis/python
```

PyCharm however does not seem to fully activate the environment. If I write a script containing

```
import os
print(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"])
```

and run it in PyCharm, all I get is my project's directory, not QGIS' extra paths.

This means that inspection and other things are not capable of actually seeing the things available in the conda environment.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72996502/4828720 has a manual workaround for adding the paths manually to the interpreter paths. Other solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180357/4828720 propose writing manual scripts. But those approaches are a) manual and b) would not follow updates to the package's own activation scripts, potentially leading to confusion and bugs in the future

I am not asking about the terminal as other questions do. My main interest is introspection.

Is it possible to have PyCharm run an actual activation of its conda environments without manual fiddling with scripts?