# localhost self-signed certificate across LAN in XAMPP

Tags: ssl, xampp, localhost, lan

I have localhost with ssl and working fine on my local pc but ssl doesn't work across LAN. Because I'm using self-signed certificate I have to install certificate in every PC in which I'll open site but it's only working on PC in which website is hosted but not on other PC on LAN.

I don't want to host my website online because I'm in development mode.

## My Local PC:

#### host file:

```
127.0.0.1 gofashion_chat.test
```

#### httpd-xampp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/gofashion"
    ServerName gofashion_chat.test
    ServerAlias *.gofashion_chat.test
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/gofashion"
    ServerName gofashion_chat.test
    ServerAlias *.gofashion_chat.test
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/htdocs/gofashion/cert/gofashion_chat.test/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/htdocs/gofashion/cert/gofashion_chat.test/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Certificate in browser:

[image: Certificate in browser]

## PC on LAN:

#### host file:

```
192.168.10.7 gofashion_chat.test
```

#### Certificate in browser on LAN PC:

[image: Certificate in browser on LAN PC]

In have installed server.crt on both PC

How do I solve ssl issue across LAN?

### Edit:

This is my bat file which I used to generate certificate

```
@echo off

set /p domain="Enter Domain without TLD (E.g 'facebook', 'google'): "
set /p com_tld="Enter Domain TLD (E.g 'com', 'test'): "

SET HOSTNAME=%domain%
SET DOT=%com_tld%
SET COUNTRY=US
SET STATE=KS
SET CITY=Olathe
SET ORGANIZATION=IT
SET ORGANIZATION_UNIT=IT Department
SET FULL_DOMAIN=%HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
SET EMAIL=webmaster@%FULL_DOMAIN%

SET OPENSSL_CONF=C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf

if not exist .\%HOSTNAME%.%DOT% mkdir .\%FULL_DOMAIN%

(
echo [req]
echo default_bits = 2048
echo prompt = no
echo default_md = sha256
echo req_extensions      = v3_req
echo x509_extensions     = x509_ext
echo distinguished_name  = dn
echo:
echo [dn]
echo C = %COUNTRY%
echo ST = %STATE%
echo L = %CITY%
echo O = %ORGANIZATION%
echo OU = %ORGANIZATION_UNIT%
echo emailAddress = %EMAIL%
echo CN = %FULL_DOMAIN%
echo:
echo [v3_req]
echo subjectAltName         = @alt_names
echo subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
echo authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer:always
echo basicConstraints       = critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:1
echo keyUsage               = critical, cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign
echo nsComment              = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
echo:
echo [x509_ext]
echo subjectAltName         = @alt_names
echo subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
echo authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer:always
echo basicConstraints       = critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:1
echo keyUsage               = critical, cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign
echo nsComment              = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
echo:
echo [alt_names]
echo DNS.1 = *.%FULL_DOMAIN%
echo DNS.2 = %FULL_DOMAIN%
)>%FULL_DOMAIN%\%HOSTNAME%.cnf

C:\xampp\apache\bin\openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout %FULL_DOMAIN%\server.key -days 356 -out %FULL_DOMAIN%\server.crt -config %FULL_DOMAIN%\%HOSTNAME%.cnf

echo.
echo -----
echo The certificate was provided.
echo.
pause
```

This is another I used to generate certificate.

```
@echo off

set /p domain="Enter Domain without TLD (E.g 'facebook', 'google'): "
set /p com_tld="Enter Domain TLD (E.g 'com', 'test'): "

SET HOSTNAME=%domain%
SET DOT=%com_tld%
SET COUNTRY=US
SET STATE=KS
SET CITY=Olathe
SET ORGANIZATION=IT
SET ORGANIZATION_UNIT=IT Department
SET FULL_DOMAIN=%HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
SET EMAIL=webmaster@%FULL_DOMAIN%

SET OPENSSL_CONF=C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf

if not exist .\%HOSTNAME%.%DOT% mkdir .\%FULL_DOMAIN%

(
echo [ req ]
echo default_bits        = 2048
echo default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
echo distinguished_name  = subject
echo req_extensions      = req_ext
echo x509_extensions     = x509_ext
echo string_mask         = utf8only
echo:
echo [ subject ]
echo countryName                 = Country Name ^(2 letter code^)
echo countryName_default         = %COUNTRY%
echo stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name ^(full name^)
echo stateOrProvinceName_default = %STATE%
echo localityName                = Locality Name ^(eg, city^)
echo localityName_default        = %CITY%
echo organizationName            = Organization Name ^(eg, company^)
echo organizationName_default    = %ORGANIZATION%
echo commonName                  = Common Name ^(e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name^)
echo commonName_default          = %HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
echo emailAddress                = Email Address
echo emailAddress_default        = %EMAIL%
echo:
echo [ x509_ext ]
echo subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
echo authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
echo basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
echo keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
echo subjectAltName         = @alternate_names
echo nsComment              = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
echo:
echo [ req_ext ]
echo subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
echo basicConstraints     = CA:FALSE
echo keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
echo subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
echo nsComment            = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"
echo:
echo [ alternate_names ]
echo:
echo DNS.1 = *.%HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
echo DNS.2 = %HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
)>%FULL_DOMAIN%\%HOSTNAME%.cnf

C:\xampp\apache\bin\openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout %FULL_DOMAIN%\server.key -days 356 -out %FULL_DOMAIN%\server.crt -config %FULL_DOMAIN%\%HOSTNAME%.cnf

echo.
echo -----
echo The certificate was provided.
echo.
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but it is worth a try ^_^

Instead of specifying your localhost with gofashion_chat.test, just use computername.domain. This will save you time editing the hosts of each computer you want to access your website.

Create a folder inside apache. Folder name: crt

Create a file with the name of cert-template.conf and save it in crt folder. Below is the command for cert-template.conf.

```
[ req ]

default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only

[ subject ]

countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = TE

stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = TEST

localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = TEST

organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = TEST

commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default          = computername.domain

emailAddress                = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer

basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName         = @alternate_names
nsComment              = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ req_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier = hash

basicConstraints     = CA:FALSE
keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
nsComment            = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = computername.domain
```

Create this file also: make-cert.bat  and save it in crt folder. Below is the command of make-cert.bat.

```
@echo off
set /p domain="Domain Name: "
set OPENSSL_CONF=../conf/openssl.cnf

REM
REM Read the "cert-template.conf" file and replace all {{DOMAIN}} placeholders by the entered domain.
REM Write the result into a new file called "cert.conf".
REM
REM @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file#20227248
REM
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=cert-template.conf
set OUTTEXTFILE=cert.conf
set SEARCHTEXT={{DOMAIN}}
set REPLACETEXT=%domain%

if exist %OUTTEXTFILE% del /F %OUTTEXTFILE%
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"findstr /n ^^ %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
   SET string=%%A
   for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%a in ("!string!") do set "string=%%b"
   if  "!string!" == "" (
       echo.>>%OUTTEXTFILE%
   ) else (
      SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
      echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
  )
)


REM
REM Create the target directory.
REM
if not exist .\%domain% mkdir .\%domain%


REM
REM Create the certificate and key files.
REM
..\bin\openssl req -config %OUTTEXTFILE% -new -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout %domain%\server.key -x509 -days 365 -out %domain%\server.crt


REM
REM Delete the written file "cert.conf" as this file would only be used to create the certificate.
REM
if exist %OUTTEXTFILE% del /F %OUTTEXTFILE%


echo.
echo -----
echo The certificate was provided.
echo.
pause
```

Run make-cert.bat, a command prompt will show and ask you for a domain name. Your domain name is your computername.domain. After that, there are question you need to answer and the most important question is the Common Name. Common Name = Computername.domain.

Install the certificate you created located at crt/computername.domain/server.crt. Install Certificate>Local Machine> Place all certificates in the following store> Browse> Trusted Root Certification Authorities> Next > Finish.

Insert this script in the bottom of httpd-xampp.conf

```
 <VirtualHost computername.domain:8080>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost computername.domain:4433>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/computername.domain/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/computername.domain/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

Restart XAMPP and try to access your localhost using https://computername.domain:4433.

That's all. I hope you get all of the steps.

Answer (score -1):

Your screenshot shows that the used certificate is allowed for the purposes

- All issuance policies
- All application policies

But you want to use it an web server certificate, therefore the certificate requires the following purpose:

- Ensures the identity of a remote computer

I assume on your computer it works as the web browser recognizes that the server is running on a local network interface - hence it is not a "remote computer" and therefore it works without this purpose allowed in the certificate.

Comment: I don't know anything about those details. I'm first time. Can you provide a solution? What should I do to get rid of this error from PC on LAN?

Comment: @Faizan Once a certificate has been signed it's data can't be changed. Therefore you have to generate and sign a new certificate - see e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/150978

Comment: but how did you self sign certificate with "Ensures the identity of a remote computer"? __openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365__ won't add "Ensures the identity of a remote computer" in certificate

Comment: @Faizan Looks like you have to configure the `keyUsage` via config file: https://superuser.com/questions/738612/openssl-ca-keyusage-extension

Comment: I have add my bat file code in question above. Check it out. I have used configuration described by you and still can't get certificate to access ssl from lan or remote computer