# Find and Replace text using Batch files

Tags: batch-file, replace

I need a batch file which searches a text file for a string and replaces it with another string. I tried to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333754/problem-with-search-and-replace-batch-file) but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
@echo off
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

if not exist "%1" (echo FindAndReplace: File Not Found)
set /p findX= Find ?
set /p replaceWithX= Replace With ?

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (%1) do (
    set str=%%G
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set str=!str:[%findX%]=[%replaceWithX%]!
    >> %1.txt echo(!str!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-enviro

Comment: You're saying the question I linked to answered your question?

Comment: An answer to that question works fine

Answer (score 0):

A bit of code that would help would be the find command here is the help menu of it

Searches for a text string in a file or files.

```
FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

/V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.
/C         Displays only the count of lines containing the string.
/N         Displays line numbers with the displayed lines.
/I         Ignores the case of characters when searching for the string.
/OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
"string"   Specifies the text string to find.
[drive:][path]filename
         Specifies a file or files to search.

If a path is not specified, FIND searches the text typed at the prompt
or piped from another command.
```